# Getting window is not defined in next.js middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, metamask

I'm building web3 project, In which if the user is logged in via metamask, I want to check for `window.ethereum` for any change in metamask account change by the user,

Currently I can think for writting middleware in next.js for checking that, but getting `window is not defined` in console.

in _middleware.ts file

```
declare let window: any

export function middleware() {
  if (typeof window === 'object' && window.ethereum) {
    console.log('HAVE METAMASK')
    window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function () {
      console.log('Account changed')
    })
  } else {
    console.log('NO METAMASK')
  }
}
```

I'm getting `NO METAMASK` being printed in the console, and when I tried to print `window` getting window is not defined error

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Please [search thoroughly](/search?q=%5Bnextjs%5D+window+is+undefined) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching). To handle SSR correctly, your `if` should be `if (typeof window === "object" && window.ethereum)`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I changed the condition but still getting `window is not defined` error

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I edited the question too, still having same error

Comment: The code that's now in the question will not cause that error. Either you're not running that code (did some build step get omitted?), or the error is coming from other code where you'd done the same thing as the original question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  there is only one file with this code  also I restarted server several times, [check this image](https://imgur.com/a/ViWsgMn)

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. That code **will not** cause that error. Full stop. It's not like there's wiggle room here. [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/xc1e9ntk/) that code with `window` changed to `wdw` so it won't be defined in the browser; as you can see, no error, just the `else` condition. [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2v8k.png) of running that code in Node.js (so `window` won't be defined). No error. So what I would do is not focus on code that isn't causing the error, but instead look for code that **is** causing the error.